# How to monitor table structure changes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to monitor a certain table structure changes in SQL Server.

For example let say i have below table;

**Existing**

```
ID,int,not null
Name,varchar, null
```

**Changed**

```
ID,int,not null
Name,varchar, null
Lastname, varchar, null
```

Is it possible to know if a new column added into this table with a SQL query? I would like to find that newly added column in specific.

I tried this one; but it's not giving me the newly added column name.

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(sc.[object_id]) as [table]
    ,sc.[name] as [column]
    ,so.modify_date
    ,so.create_date
  FROM [sys].[columns] sc
  JOIN [sys].[objects] so
  ON sc.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
  ORDER BY so.modify_date DESC
```

Any idea?

Comment: This might help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165283/ddl-changes-tracking

Comment: No amount of code will compensate for a development process that has is not managed. Nor will it compensate for developers that make schema changes without communicating or consulting with the rest of the team. Your schema should be source controlled - just like your application code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a ddl trigger on the database

```
create table dbo.logtablechanges
(
    tableobject_id int,
    tablename sysname,
    columnname sysname,--log a single column alteration
    theaction varchar(50),
    actionbylogin sysname constraint df_logtablechanges_actionbylogin default(original_login()),
    thestatement nvarchar(max),
    thedate datetime constraint df_logtablechanges_thedate default(getdate())
);
go

create table dbo.guineapigtbl(id int identity);
insert into dbo.guineapigtbl default values;
select * from guineapigtbl;
go

create trigger trig_db_alter_table on database
for ALTER_TABLE 
as
begin

    declare @d xml = EVENTDATA();

    declare @tblschemaname sysname, 
            @tblname sysname, 
            @action varchar(20),
            @colname sysname,
            @sqlcommand nvarchar(max);

    --for multiple columns      
    select 
        @tblschemaname = @d.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname'),
        @tblname = @d.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname'),
        @action = @d.value('local-name((/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/*)[1])', 'varchar(20)'),
        --change this for multiple columns (depends on the logging)
        @colname = @d.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/*[1]/Columns/Name)[1]', 'sysname'),
        @sqlcommand = @d.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');


    if object_id(quotename(@tblschemaname) + '.' + quotename(@tblname)) = object_id('dbo.guineapigtbl')
      and @colname is not null
    begin
        insert into dbo.logtablechanges
        (
            tableobject_id, 
            tablename, columnname,  theaction, thestatement
        )
        values
        (
            object_id(quotename(@tblschemaname) + '.' + quotename(@tblname)),
            @tblname, @colname, @action, @sqlcommand
        )

    end

end
go


--testing
alter table dbo.guineapigtbl add col1 int;
alter table dbo.guineapigtbl add col2 varchar(10);
alter table dbo.guineapigtbl alter column col1 bigint;
alter table dbo.guineapigtbl drop column col1;

--multiple
alter table dbo.guineapigtbl add col3 int, col4 int;

--check log
select *
from logtablechanges

--cleanup
/*
drop table dbo.logtablechanges
drop table dbo.guineapigtbl
drop trigger trig_db_alter_table on database

go
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your code!
I edited the trigger that all tables of the database will be monitored, not just the specific one at "= object_id('dbo.guineapigtbl')"

```
ALTER trigger trig_db_alter_table on database
for ALTER_TABLE 
as
begin

    declare @d xml = EVENTDATA();

    declare @tblschemaname sysname, 
            @tblname sysname, 
            @action varchar(20),
            @colname sysname,
            @sqlcommand nvarchar(max),
            
            @WHILE_Count int,
            @WHILE_Count_Max int;

    --for multiple columns      
    select 
        @tblschemaname = @d.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname'),
        @tblname = @d.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname'),
        @action = @d.value('local-name((/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/*)[1])', 'varchar(20)'),
        --change this for multiple columns (depends on the logging)
        @colname = @d.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/*[1]/Columns/Name)[1]', 'sysname'),
        @sqlcommand = @d.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');

    CREATE TABLE #TMP_list_of_tables_in_DB
        (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,object_id_table int
        )

    INSERT INTO #TMP_list_of_tables_in_DB
        (object_id_table)
    SELECT 
        (object_id)
    FROM [DBNAME].sys.objects
        WHERE TYPE IN('P','T','FN','u')
        AND TYPE_DESC = 'USER_TABLE'

    SET @WHILE_Count = 1
    SET @WHILE_Count_Max = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #TMP_list_of_tables_in_DB)

    WHILE @WHILE_Count <= @WHILE_Count_Max

    BEGIN

    if object_id(quotename(@tblschemaname) + '.' + quotename(@tblname)) = (SELECT object_id_table FROM #TMP_list_of_tables_in_DB WHERE ID = @WHILE_Count)
      and @colname is not null
    begin
        insert into dbo.logtablechanges
        (
            tableobject_id, 
            tablename, columnname,  theaction, thestatement
        )
        values
        (
            object_id(quotename(@tblschemaname) + '.' + quotename(@tblname)),
            @tblname, @colname, @action, @sqlcommand
        )

    end

    SET @WHILE_Count = @WHILE_Count + 1

    END

    DROP TABLE #TMP_list_of_tables_in_DB

end
```